# Sum user working time in a given MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

The following table has the time when the user enters/quit on the company:

```
ID | user_id | day_unix   | time
10   1         1459220400   1459293745  
9    1         1459220400   1459293711  
8    1         1459220400   1459293689  
7    1         1459220400   1459293678  
6    1         1459220400   1459293669  
11   1         1459220400   1459293761
```

`day_unix` consists in the first second of the day, this way, `GROUP BY` can be easily used in future.

`time` consists in the time that the user click's on the button to start/stop working. Time also can be changed to a native `DATETIME` column.

I want to create a SQL query capable of summing the time between the entries. So the query must to jump "odd" entries that can be considered as the beginnig of a small coffee break and right after the "odd" entries the user has started working again, so the query must to sum the working time, excluding the coffee breaks.

Any idea? Here is what I've already got:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY day_unix ORDER BY time ASC
```

Comment: Why can't you use native `DATETIME` columns? UNIX time is really obnoxious to deal with in the MySQL context.

Comment: It can be changed! @tadman

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.

Comment: You need to define what exactly you mean by "odd" entries and hoe to identify them, preferably showing desired results based on your sample data.

Comment: @YgorMontenegro I'd strongly recommend going with native datatypes. If your data is coming in via UNIX epoch time, there's functions to convert it, like [`FROM_UNIXTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). Once you get it in a native format you can do things like `DATE_SUB` on values to get differences.